# Create serial numbers in a new column

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In postgres, we can add a new incremental column like:

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> 
    ADD IF NOT EXISTS <column_name> SERIAL;
```

Which creates new column in the table with serial numbers. In snowflake when I tried the same command, it's throwing an error

> SQL compilation error: Unsupported data type 'SERIAL'.

How can the same behavior be achieved in Snowflake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The SERIAL pseudo-type is an auto-incremented integer with a storage size of four bytes and a range of one to 2,147,483,647.

You can use AUTOINCREMENT or IDENTITY to have the same feature:

```
create or replace table test ( id number AUTOINCREMENT, v varchar ) ;

insert into test (v) values ('Test1'),('Test2'),('Test3');

select * from test;

+----+-------+
| ID |   V   |
+----+-------+
|  1 | Test1 |
|  2 | Test2 |
|  3 | Test3 |
+----+-------+
```

https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00008xAsQ0/how-to-set-auto-identity-column-from-alter-table-statement

PS: It's not possible to add such a column after creating the table.

Comment: I proceeded with this approach only.
Syntax is same if anybody using 'copy into command'
`copy into test (v) from table_name file_format**`

Comment: https://www.datameer.com/blog/add-identity-or-autoincrement-to-table-in-snowflake/